# Magento Shopping Cart Rules including simple and configurable products

Tags: magento

I am currently having an issue with setting up a shopping cart rule in Magento CE 1.6.1, we have configurable products set up with simple products underneath them, we are currently trying to set up a shopping cart rule to say that if there are 4 products from one category apply a discount.

Currently to get this to work, we have to set the qty rule in Magento to 5 or greater. This works if all 4 products are the same, however if you use different products then you need to up the qty by 1 each time in the back end of Magento.

I assume that this is due to the fact it is adding the 4 simple products and then is adding the one configurable product. Is there a way to stop this so it only looks for the simple products?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get product type in cart rule, I feel you should create new attribute for configurable or simple products and use that attribute as condition in shopping cart price rule.

Answer (score 0):

There was an answer [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5310/add-a-product-type-condition-to-a-shopping-cart-rule) that might help you:

> The configurable subproducts were all Visibility 'not individually
>   visible' so I could filter on this property to solve the problem.